# Dynamics CRM: Compare CRM environments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a tool out there to compare CRM environments?  Recently we implemented a third party managed solution that changed a bunch of settings on our Contact entity.  An example of this is that auditing was turned off.

Ideally we would like to compare our Dev environment (where the third party solution is installed) to our QA environment (where the third party solution isn't installed) to determine the differences.

We are CRM 2013 Online.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: If you were on-premise you could compare queries from metadata tables such as entitybase.  My guess is that you don't have this option since you are online?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, ***tool***, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: from a Dynamics CRM perspective this is a valid question. As you can see from the answer the proposed solution is part of the Software Development Kit and not any arbitrary tool. Also the question is more about the approach. So great question.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest thing I know of is to do a full Solution Export of both environments, export the solutions, then compare them using something like beyond compare.  You can optionally use the [Solution Packager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx) to help in splitting the files.

If you're only concerned about fields and entities that have been added or removed, I would use the [Early Bound Generator](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/) to create the earlybound types and do a compare on those files.