# D365: Compare solution before import

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to import solution using a windows form application.

For that I'm using `ImportSolutionRequest`. But before initiating import into solution, I want to check if that solution is already imported or not.

For this, one approach can be using `QueryExpression` which will fetch the specific  columns and then I can match it with current version by navigating through the `CustomizationFile`.

Is there any other possible way that I can compare the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to compare solutions is to export both, unzip them, and run a "diff" on the customizations.xml files.

"Diff" tools include: Visual Studio, WinMerge, BeyondCompare.

There was also a [tool on CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=crmcomparer) that would run a compare between solutions and produce a report. Perhaps you can adapt that code to run the comparison within your custom code.

For further reference:

[Dynamics CRM: Compare CRM environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762465/dynamics-crm-compare-crm-environments)

https://develop1.net/public/post/2013/08/07/Compare-customisations-between-two-Dynamics-CRM-Organisations